# How to install libfuse2 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, package, appimage, lts, libfuse

I have an app image that I want to install but I get the following error when trying to run it
[image]

On trying to install the libfuse2 package this is the error I get

[image]

I'd appreciate any help that will help in installation and running of the App image

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. You might want to explore our sibling site [ubuntu.se], but please read their help pages before asking there (and please delete this off-topic post, and review our [help] before posting here again). Also, please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)